# Angular guard Routes by token in cookies

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, jwt, local-storage

I usually save user token in local storage. I check "token" key in local storage as CanActivate method to protect some routes. If the key is there i let the user land on the page, otherwise i redirect to login page.

Now I'm using cookies to store the auth token. Token is stored in cookies directly upon login by the server (set-cookie, secure: true, httpOnly: true).

Because of httpOnly, I can't check if token is stored or not from js, and I don't know how to guard my routes. How can I accomplish a similar handling like I did before? Should I save something in local storage anyways upon login and just check if the key is there? Can I check if the key is stored in cookies in some way?

Comment: Why did you change something that works ?

Comment: Because storing jwt inside local storage is less secure than storing it as a cookie

Comment: That's a bold statement, could I know where you get that from ?

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/

Comment: In addition, storing in cookies is a requirement. So i need to accomplish it in this way

Comment: So, on a opinionated website, where it doesn't actually says that local storage is less secure. And they explain how to use the cookies there, so why posting a question here ? And why would cookies be a requirement, if the local storage was used before ? My answer is to keep using local storage, you won't have security issues (and by the way, JWT are secured and can't be decrypted without the key, so even if you managed to let someone hack a token, he won't be able to decrypt it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use NPM package **ngx-cookie-service**.

```
npm install ngx-cookie-service
```

In your app.module

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
```

In a component

```
constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}
…
public ngOnInit() {
    this.cookieService.set('cookie-name','cookie value');
    let cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('cookie-name');
}
```

https://itnext.io/angular-8-how-to-use-cookies-14ab3f2e93fc

Regards

Comment: httponly cookies are not accessible by client, that is the main reason behind keeping the token in a cookie so a script can not read it.

Answer (score 0):

When I get the first login response,I return the token to client as well as setting the httponly cookie and  I parse the token that I returned only once and I only store the payload of the token, not the whole token, which has user_id and expiration date and use it in my guard to check against as a flag. 
I also have an httpinterceptor which checks for 401 errors which re routes to login.
So if it expires, i set the local storage to null or if I ever get 401 error I also set the stored user_id and expiration date to null.

You ll find out actually the worst part of httponly cookie is to send a logout request to server to expire the cookie on serverside and also have a blacklist which holds the token and userid in model so you know once you are logged out you save that token,

Another issue is refreshment of tokens, make sure to keep the exp time of the first token to 5 minutes or so and refresh when needed.

Comment: when using angular guards, do you simply check for the presence of a user_id and whether the current time is less than or greater than expiration time to return a value (true, redirectURL or other appropriate response) to the guard? Also, what the point of maintaining a blacklist with token/userID after a user logs out?